# Python - Ppm value RGB in a matrix without library

Tags: python, matrix, rgb, ppm

I'm trying to recover separately value R, G & B from a ppm file in three different matrices.

I wrote this script :

```py
#Read file
feep_file = open("feep.ascii.ppm", "r")

def createMatrixRGB(filename):
    matrixR = []
    matrixG = []
    matrixB = []
    tableR = []
    tableG = []
    tableB = []
    tmp = False
    for lines in filename:
        x = lines.split()
        for y in x:
            if(y == 0 and tmp == False):
                tableR.append(y)
            if(y == 1 and tmp == False):
                tableG.append(y)
            if(y == 2 and tmp == False):
                tableB.append(y)
        tmp = True
    matrixR.append(tableR)
    matrixG.append(tableG)
    matrixB.append(tableB)
    tableR = []
    tableG = []
    tableB = []

    return matrixR, matrixB, matrixG

#Read lines
magic_number = feep_file.readline()
name_file = feep_file.readline()
dimension = feep_file.readline()
k = feep_file.readline()
print(magic_number)
ppm_matrix = createMatrixRGB(feep_file)
feep_file.close()
print(ppm_matrix)
```

The problem is that I have this result :

```py
P3

([[]], [[]], [[]])
```

I don't see where I did something wrong.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please add to your post a small sample PPM image data as text (8x8 pixels for example)? Note: Some files stats with a comment as [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/ppma/ppma.html).

Comment: it's with the feep.ascii.ppm I'm trying that

Comment: Your code looks more complicated that it should have. What is the purpose? Is it a coding practice?

Comment: yes it is, i can't solve the problem

Comment: It looks like it's time for debugging practice... What IDE are you using? Do you know how to itterate the code step by step? Do you know how to watch the variable while debugging?

Comment: I use PyCharm (sorry for this late response i didn't saw your comment)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is not converting strings to integers, and the usage of `y` as an index.

Since it's a coding practice, I am not going to just give a solution.
I will try to show you how to use the debugger to find the problem.

Place a breakpoint, run with Debug, and add `x` and `y` to the watch:
[image]

As you can see, the value of `y` is `'0'`, and the type is `str`.

---

You can also evaluate expressions in the debugger Console (while debugging).
Paste the expression: `y == 0 and tmp == False`:
[image]

As you can see, the expression: `y == 0 and tmp == False` evaluates to `False`.
You may run a single step, and notice that the cursor doesn't step to `tableR.append(y)` (but skip to `if(y == 1 and tmp == False)`), because the condition is `False`.

The reason we are getting `False` is that `y` == `'0'`, but not `0`.

---

Now evaluate the expression after converting `y` to `int`:
`int(y) == 0 and tmp == False`:
[image]

As you can see `int(y) == 0` is `True`.

---

After all that...
I don't think you have meant to use the value of `y`.
I think you meant to use the index of `y` in `x`.

[Note: Your conventions are wrong - normally `y` is the line, and `x` is the position in the line, but I kept your names].

---

Corrected code (at least partially corrected):

```
#Read file
feep_file = open("feep.ascii.ppm", "r")

def createMatrixRGB(filename):
    matrixR = []
    matrixG = []
    matrixB = []
    tableR = []
    tableG = []
    tableB = []

    for lines in filename:
        x = lines.split()
        color_index = 0
        for y in x:
            if color_index % 3 == 0:  # Use color_index modulo 3 (like counting 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2...)
                tableR.append(int(y))
            if color_index % 3 == 1:
                tableG.append(int(y))
            if color_index % 3 == 2:
                tableB.append(int(y))
            color_index += 1

        matrixR.append(tableR)
        matrixG.append(tableG)
        matrixB.append(tableB)

        tableR = []
        tableG = []
        tableB = []

    return matrixR, matrixB, matrixG

#Read lines
magic_number = feep_file.readline()
name_file = feep_file.readline()
dimension = feep_file.readline()
k = feep_file.readline()
print(magic_number)
ppm_matrix = createMatrixRGB(feep_file)
feep_file.close()
print(ppm_matrix)
```

---

Result:

`([[0, 0, 0, 15], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [15, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 15], [0, 7, 0, 0], [0, 0, 7, 0], [15, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 15, 0, 0], [0, 0, 15, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])`

---

Comment: Oh ok ok thank you for your help